# Association : client.order , ok but how do you retrieve the client from the order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read the following rails guide : http://guides.rails.info/active_record_querying.html

in there exemple a client has many orders and orders belong to clients.

They explain how to find a lot of stuff from client. But if i want all orders from yesterday, with the corresponding client name, how do i retrieve the client from an order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# controller
@orders = Order.all(:include => :client,
   :conditions => ["created_at = ?", Date.today-1])

# view
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
   <%= order.client.name %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit:**

If you have an specific order `id`, you can do your search like

```
@order = Order.first(id, :include => :client)
```

and access the client the same way

```
@order.client.name
```

Comment: ok, i understand it better now. and if i have a specific order, i do :
order(:include=>client, :conditions=> id=order.client_id)
?

Comment: you Should be able to do `Order.find(id, :include = :client)`

Answer (score 0):

```
today = Date.today
yesterday = today - 1.days
orders = Order.find(:all, :include => :client, :conditions => ["created_at >= :yesterday AND created_at <= :today", {:yesterday => yesterday, :today => today}])
```

You can now iterate `orders` and do `order.client` to retrieve the Client object. The `:include => :client` will make RoR automatically include the it in the query (rather than lazy loading).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
orders = Order.all(:conditions => ["DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)",
                   :include => :client,
                   Time.now - 1.day])
client = orders.first.client
```